# Issue with UITextField's leftView property

Tags: swift, io, uitextfield

I am trying to add a single blank `UIView` to multiple `UITextField` in order to give a little padding. But my app freeze (does not crash). Can anyone tell me what the issue might be? Here is my code.

```
var paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 50))
```

It works well when I assign this view to single `UITextField`

```
 emailTextField.leftView = paddingView 
 emailTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

But App does not responds if I add same paddingView to another `UITextField` e.g

```
someTextField.leftView = paddingView 
someTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```

My Environment is xCode 6.4, Swift 2.0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, I was having and issue with the same exact problem.  My solution was to create a paddingView for each textfield.

```
var paddingView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 50))
var paddingView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 10, height: 50))

emailTextField.leftView = paddingView 
emailTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always

someTextField.leftView = paddingView2
someTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
```